# Use Query to Dynamically add/remove input fields depending on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, dynamic

I downloaded a form from CodeCanyon and I can edit the form pretty well as is I think, but there is a change I need to make that is beyond my capabilities and any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

I need to set the form up so that when a user selects yes from a radio button a validated input pops up, then when no is selected the input is removed.

Then on validation all radio button questions must have either selected.

So the form would look something like:

---

Label -> Question 1

Radio -> Yes // {No}

---

Label -> Question 2

Radio -> {Yes} // No

Input -> 3400

---

Label -> Question 3

Radio -> {Yes} // No

Input -> 550

---

---

Then the form's email would send the following:

Question 1: No

Question 2: 3400

Question 3: 550

```
<form method="post" class="DA_custom_form" id="registration-form" action="email.php">
    <h3>Dynamic Radio Section</h3>

    <div class="DA_inner_frame">

        <div class="DA_holder">
            <label>Radio Question 1</label>

            <div class="DA_holder DA_radio_holder">
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="question1" id="question1" value="yes" /><label class="fl">Yes</label>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="question1" id="question1" value="no"  /><label class="fl">No</label>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>

        </div>

        <!--Show on Yes --><div class="DA_holder">
            <label>Text field for question 1: Yes</label>
            <div class="DA_field_container" >
                <div class="cl" >&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="text" class="field" id="question1" name="question1" placeholder='Range Validation 2000-4000'/>
                <span><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="DA_holder">
            <label>Radio Question 2</label>

            <div class="DA_holder DA_radio_holder">
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="question2" id="question2" value="yes" /><label class="fl">Yes</label>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="questio2" id="question2" value="no"  /><label class="fl">No</label>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>

        </div>

        <!--Show on Yes --><div class="DA_holder">
            <label>Text field for question 2: Yes</label>
            <div class="DA_field_container" >
                <div class="cl" >&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="text" class="field" id="question2" name="question2" placeholder='Range Validation 500-1000'/>
                <span><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="DA_holder">
            <label>Radio Question 3</label>

            <div class="DA_holder DA_radio_holder">
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="question3" id="question3" value="yes" /><label class="fl">Yes</label>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="questio3" id="question3" value="no"  /><label class="fl">No</label>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>

        </div>

        <!--Show on Yes --><div class="DA_holder">
            <label>Text field for question 3: Yes</label>
            <div class="DA_field_container" >
                <div class="cl" >&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="text" class="field" id="question3" name="question3" placeholder='Range Validation 500-1000'/>
                <span><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>  
        </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Please show us the HTML for your form (including the dynamic parts) so we can advise more specifically how to do what you're asking.  The generic answer is that you use the `.change()` event in jQuery to respond to radio changes and then you show/hide sections of the form based on the values upon change.

Comment: I am trying to create a fiddle page with where I am at, but honestly I am at ground zero working my way up. I will continue to update the page as I move along. 

Teaching myself is fun, but sometimes long..
Thanks in advance

Comment: All I asked for is the HTML you're starting with for you fields.  We can't provide jQuery code that operates on your HTML without seeing your HTML.  Do you not even yet have HTML?

Comment: I have a static html base that I am working off of that I built from the template, but that is it. 

Here is the HTML that I have.
http://jsfiddle.net/eyeyb6zm/

Comment: Please copy the HTML (or a representative sample of the HTML) into your question per the StackOverflow guidelines (you can use the Edit link to edit your question).  External references that are essential to understanding and answering the question are not permitted because they have a way of disappearing over time and then the question is no longer complete.

Comment: OK, thx for posting the HTML.  Based on that, I've provided an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle the input field after the question with this jQuery:

```
$(".DA_radio_holder .radio-btn").change(function() {
    // get appropriate level parent and toggle the next one at that level
    // based on the value of the radio
    $(this).closest(".DA_radio_holder").parent().next()
       .toggle(this.value === 'yes');
});
```

You could make the code simpler and more maintainable if you gave the question parent div and the text field parent div each their own unique class.  Then, you could also set defaults for visibility on the text fields via CSS.

For example, by adding the class `"question"` to the question parent and the class `"textField"` to the text field parent as here:

```
        <div class="DA_holder question">
            <label>Radio Question 1</label>

            <div class="DA_holder DA_radio_holder">
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="question1" id="question1" value="yes" /><label class="fl">Yes</label>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="question1" id="question1" value="no"  /><label class="fl">No</label>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>

        </div>

        <!--Show on Yes --><div class="DA_holder textField">
            <label>Text field for question 1: Yes</label>
            <div class="DA_field_container" >
                <div class="cl" >&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="text" class="field" id="question1" name="question1" placeholder='Range Validation 2000-4000'/>
                <span><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

Then, the code just becomes this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".DA_radio_holder .radio-btn").change(function() {
        // get appropriate level parent and toggle the next one at that level
        // based on the value of the radio
        $(this).closest(".question").next().toggle(this.value === 'yes');
    });
});
```

And, you could start out with all text fields hidden with this CSS:

```
.DA_holder.textField {display: none;}
```

Working demo of this second option: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vjbb4t9p/

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to do. Though could you explain how I create the parent classes for "question" and "textField"?

Comment: @wenzday - Those classes are in the HTML in my answer and in the jsFiddle I linked to.  Just look for them there.

Comment: I saw the additions in the fiddle example, but didn't know if I can to add anything else to my CSS file besides the textField hide. 

Then I didn't know if the page had to be on a server for the jquery to run, so I uploaded it to the web, but it still does not "show" on yes. 

I placed the javescript text in the fiddle in the top of the html page in the <script type="text/javascript"> area

Comment: @wenzday - If your page is laid out properly and you've included jQuery in your page, it all works just fine.  I can't really help with what you've done without seeing the actual page so I can see what you have.

Comment: I don't know if we are allowed to ad pages, but if not I will delete this comment. http://paiddot.com/ebs/registration/web-dev.html

Comment: @wenzday - You are trying to install your event handlers too early before the page is loaded (posting external links for this reason are fine).  See how I modified the code at the end of my answer by putting it inside a `$(document).ready()` block.

Comment: I used that code in the page I posted, but I do not know how to call the .ready block. The example you gave just gives the code, but not how/where to place it.

Comment: @wenzday - You put it right where you had the block of code before.  It just gets wrapped in the ready handler like I show.  The `.ready()` handler will get called automatically by jQuery when the DOM had finished loading.

Comment: Do you mind taking another look at the URL I provided earlier. I changed the code to the .ready handler and put in back in the head section. The html page loads jquery-1.9.1.min.js 

I apologize the for the constant headache.

Comment: @wenzday - you have some CSS setting the radio buttons to zero height so they aren't getting the events.  in their place is some sort of `icon-circle` CSS that draws the actual radio button.  That is what is depriving you of the input events.  Do you know why you're using this custom radio button behavior?

Comment: @wenzday - If I edit out the icon-circle stuff and disable all the CSS rules that hide the actual `input` element, the code works just fine when you click on the yes and no buttons so it is that customization that is interfering with normal `input` tag behavior.

Comment: No honestly I do not. The CSS was pre-defined from the author at codecanyon.

Comment: @wenzday - it appears that the custom CSS is wrecking the behavior of the radio buttons.  It needs to be removed or a bunch of new code needs to be written to handle the state changes on these new objects (code that already exists for free in the `input` objects).